# Android studio multiple splash screens

Tags: android

I recently tried creating more than one splash screen but I didn't work and I don't know how to do . I don't have any code to post because I deleted it but if someone can link me to a good tutorial that would help .

Answer (score 1):

Of course you cannot display 2 splash screens at a time. However, you can build with Android variants that change splash screens on different conditions:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Gradle_Build_Variants_Example

Answer (score 0):

You can start second splash screen from first splash screen , third from second and so on, at particular time interval.

Try this :

```
public class FirstSplash extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstSplash.this, SecondSplash .class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Use same code in second splash screen to open third splash.

Here I take 1 second time to change switch between splash screens.You can take as your desire.